# AJAX $.ajax() and setInterval() only loading when someone is on page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I wrote the code below to refresh or reload the page to a div id='bitcoin_blocks_table' and it only does so when someone is on the site.

If nobody is on the site and I come back in 2 hours it didn't update the ones from the past two hours.

Is this because of the AJAX call or could it be because of the script?

Code:

```
            $('#bitcoin_blocks_table').load('./ajax/bitcoin_blocks.php');

            var refresh_bitcoin_blocks = setInterval(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: './ajax/bitcoin_blocks.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(blocks) {
                        $('#bitcoin_blocks_table').html(blocks);
                    }
                });
            }, 10000);
```

Comment: What did you expect? That your javascript code magically keeps running if there is no browser open to run it in? The timer is managed by the browser.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the site "works" only when somebody opens it. The intervals work within a client (browser), and once it's closed, so are the intervals... Imagine what would happen if all the periodic JS functions on every site would run (and add up with every new visit) the whole time!

Google "cron job".

Answer (score 0):

run your script

```
/ajax/bitcoin_blocks.php
```

via cronjob

see this [article](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/)